# is it possible to program in c language to search something in google and show the first search result as output?

Tags: c

i am curious to know is it possible to write program in c language to search something in google and show the first search result as output accessing network?
Is yes please tell me how with some codes.

Comment: Of course it's possible: that's what your browser does (among many other things) and it's written in C++. It's a lot of work, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some helpful references (don't ask for complete code here, do it yourself! if you run into errors, ask about them here):

1. [Google's opinion on automated queries](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66357?hl=en)
2. [C program example to fetch an html resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368410/tcp-client-fetches-html-in-c-socket)
3. [A possible way to do what you wanted](https://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-get-a-Google-Search-API-for-C%2B%2B/answer/Md-Minhazul-Haque?srid=u21Vr) (combine this answer with reference #2)

Good luck!